# Serve & upload image as part of an entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vuejs2

I have an entity like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner_type")
public class PartnerType {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "picture_address")
    private String picture;

    @Column
    private String country;
//....
}
```

And I would like to store files related to this entity on disk and store the name of the file ( picture attribute ) in the database. (Is it the best solution ?)

So when I load the entity I would like to load the picture and send it to VueJs client.

And when I create an entity from VueJs client I would like to store the picture name in the database and store the picture on disk.

I've already read and tested the article :  [Uploading files with spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

and read some other articles but they always speak about upload just the file and not the file as part of an entity...

So lets say that I would like to show every  `PartnerType` in a VueJS view with the name, country and picture of the type. How to do It from spring boot?